# Which is the best preposition to follow "demanding"?

Tags: prepositions

My previous referral report demanding on urgent transfer of the patient to your hospital.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Even if you did make it clear, it is unlikely this would be on topic because it sounds like it would be Primarily Opinion Based. Please see the help page ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: *Demand* is a transitive verb: it takes a direct object, not a prepositional oblique. The ***noun*** *demand* takes a prepositional oblique with *for*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is based on a misconception.

Answer (score 2):

The example sentence requires no preposition:

"My previous referral report demanding urgent transfer of the patient to your hospital..."

Please note that this is a sentence fragment, and should be changed to something like

> My previous referral report demanded urgent transfer of the patient to your hospital.

or

> My previous referral report demanding urgent transfer of the patient to your hospital was disregarded!